# Encoding french special chars ExtJS

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, utf-8

I have an application developed with ExtJS. I use ext-locale-fr.js.

My index.html starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

My file is encoded in UTF-8 and the encoding in my browser is "Unicode".

If I understand well, I don't need to use HTML entities for my special chars, because I'm in UTF-8. So if I write the word "Évènement" in my code, it's supposed to be correctly written in my browser. Unfortunately, it appears like that :

```
�v�nement
```

If i use HTML entitites, it is correctly displayed.

Moreover, I use sencha-charts in this application, and the charts are drawn using HTML5 canvas element, which doesn't interpret HTML entities. So in my chart, the word is displayed :

```
&Eacute;v&egrave;nement
```

I managed to bypass it using a cheat I found on the internet :

```
decodeHtml: function (html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
}
```

But I think it's not really a good practice.

Last thing, I overwrote the ext-locale-fr.js to replace all the special chars by their corresponding HTML entity. But it's the only trick that doesn't work. In the date picker, the months are not correctly displayed and the � still appears, but I can't use my decodeHtml trick.

I would like to cure the real origin of this problem, and not only the symptoms, and I have no idea what to do.

I precise that all the strings displayed in my application are directly written in my JS files and doesn't come from an ajax request.

I tested it on windows 7, with Firefox 36 and Google Chrome 40. On my computer at work there is no problem, but on my personal computer it doesn't work (and more annoying, it does'nt work on the customer's computer either).

Thank you !

If something needs to be precised, please notify me.

**EDIT**

Here are an example of it from one of my views :

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    fieldLabel: 'D&eacute;but',
    name: 'startDate',
    allowBlank: false,
    margin: '5 5 5 5'
}]
```

The result is :

[image: Result]

No problem with the label thanks to HTML Entities, but there is a problem in the name of the month in spite of the HTML entities I put in ext-locale-fr.js.

Comment: Are you really sure you edit **all** your files as utf8? It appears like your editor treats your ext-locale file as iso8859-*.

Comment: I'm quite sure, because I use brackets editor and it only opens utf-8 files.

Comment: Can you publish the problematic page or at least a part of it somewhere?

Comment: I added an brief example, I hope it will be enough

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was due to the file encoding of *.js files. Files generated with Sencha cmd were not encoded in UTF-8 and my editor respected the source encoding. Changing the encoding of the file to UTF-8 solved the problem.